# How to close my .bat window after its executed in windows XP sp3

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window

I just have two simple lines, I have tried numerous measured looked up online but can't seem to get the window to close. I am running two programs in the batch file basically. One is installing a program at Windows XP boot, and the other is adding a few registry keys. I have the .bat file being started from the registry (RUN).
When it's finished it asks to "press any key to continue". I am sure this is simple, just not exactly sure what the problem is.... Here is my RunReg.bat currently:

```
@echo off    
timeout /t 19 /nobreak    
start C:\Windows\regedit.exe /s C:\FFDRIFT\RunReg.reg    
start C:\FFDRIFT\MultiKey32\install.cmd    
exit
```

And here is the content of install.cmd:

```
@cd /d %~dp0
@devcon remove root\multikey
@devcon install multikey.inf root\multikey
@pause
```

Comment: is it your batch file that stays open or your install.cmd? Perhaps the install.cmd script would help as well.

Comment: install.cmd is a part of a program (multikey) readily avail on the net. For some reason it wont let me post its contents, but its pretty simple... removes itself, and reinstalls. only 4 small lines, and it complete fine...

Comment: Spyware/Virus related perchance?

Comment: No not at all. I wouldnt have that on my computer... Not sure what makes you think that

Comment: LINE1: cd /d %~dp0                                                                                                   
LINE2: devcon remove root\multikey                                                                      LINE3: devcon install multikey.inf root\multikey                                                                                                                             LINE4: pause                                                              There, it wouldnt let me post because each line has an "@" symbol in front of it  .... Is the pause in this file whats causing it?

Comment: Just remove the "pause" line from the end, and it will close itself.

Comment: For `RunReg.bat` remove `start` from lines 3 & 4. In `install.bat` it'll be safer to put `%~dp0` into double quotes and remove the `@pause` line.

Answer (score 1):

Command line windows close themselves automatically after their program finishes.

The `pause` command does those things you wrote. It prints out "Press any key to continue..." and pauses the program's execution until the user presses a key. ([Documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/pause.html)) So the program can't finish and the window stays open until a key press.

If you remove `pause` from `install.cmd`, then the program can finish and the window will be closed.

Comment: The press any key to continue is gone now, but the window still stays open after it completes? Might it have anything to do with me running it from the registry? I kind of had to do it that way, startup programs just was not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @roger, `start` runs a .cmd or .bat script using `cmd.exe /K`. Use `call C:\FFDRIFT\MultiKey32\install.cmd` instead.

Comment: @eryksun, Thank you so much! That was the ticket! Closes without issue!!!!  Cheers! Unfortunately I dont know how to vote your answer up lol, But it was the correct answer, to the second part of the problem anyway!!!!!

Comment: @roger, `call` shouldn't be necessary in this case either, as I have indicated in my comment below your question. Just remove both instances of `start` from that script. Also there's no need for the `exit` line either and I see no benefit in a 19 second `timeout` after nothing has happened, just start the script 19 seconds later!

Comment: ok, thank you. I appreciate the feedback! The 19 second timeout is important. I am emulating "my" hasp dongle in a game machine. It only works if I time it pretty close. Without the timeout the machine would simply overwrite the registry keys written. Seems to remove them at every reboot as well. Thus why i had to put together a simple script reinstalling all of it over at boot.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Pause command from the final line of install.cmd

Comment: Can I maybe somehow force RunReg.bat to close itself somehow? Eliminated the press any key to continue, but the window remains open...  Thank you for all your input btw

Answer (score 0):

RunReg.cmd:

```bat
@Reg Import "C:\FFDRIFT\RunReg.reg"
@"C:\FFDRIFT\MultiKey32\install.cmd"
```

install.cmd:

```bat
@DevCon Remove root\multikey
@DevCon Install "%~dp0multikey.inf" root\multikey
```

Although I see no reason why it can't all go into a single file:

```bat
@Reg Import "C:\FFDRIFT\RunReg.reg"
@DevCon Remove root\multikey
@DevCon Install "C:\FFDRIFT\MultiKey32\multikey.inf" root\multikey
```

Comment: Thanks! I will have to give this a go :)